# adding Vaadin Control Panel to Liferay (liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war does not support this version of Liferay)

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, vaadin, liferay-6, vaadin7

I would like to use Vaadin 7 with Liferay 6.2. I downloaded Vaadin Control Panel from [marketplace](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/27527287?_7_WAR_osbportlet_backURL=&_7_WAR_osbportlet_appVersionId=27527288&_7_WAR_osbportlet_cur=1&_7_WAR_osbportlet_delta=20&p_r_p_564233524_keywords=&_7_WAR_osbportlet_advancedSearch=false&_7_WAR_osbportlet_andOperator=true) and added .war to deploy folder.

Path to .war of Vaadin Control Panel: 
`/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/deploy/liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war`

Then I opened Liferay Control Panel and tried to activate Vaadin Control Panel in Apps->Utility and got error message: *"Portlet is temporarily unavailable."* In log message I got error:

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war does not support this version of Liferay
```

In log I found these error messages:

```
101 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:204] Processing Vaadin Control Panel.lpkg
105 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][LiferayPackageAutoDeployListener:51] Extracting Liferay package for /liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/deploy/Vaadin Control Panel.lpkg
107 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][LiferayPackageAutoDeployer:89] Extracting liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war from Vaadin Control Panel.lpkg
382 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][LiferayPackageAutoDeployer:89] Extracting liferay-marketplace.properties from Vaadin Control Panel.lpkg
383 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][LiferayPackageAutoDeployListener:57] Liferay package for /liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/deploy/Vaadin Control Panel.lpkg extracted successfully. Deployment will start in a few seconds.
Loading file:/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/temp/1-kaleo-web/WEB-INF/classes/service.properties
436 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:204] Processing liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war
437 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][PortletAutoDeployListener:79] Copying portlets for /liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/deploy/liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war
449 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][BaseDeployer:859] Deploying liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war
453 ERROR [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:220] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war does not support this version of Liferay
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war does not support this version of Liferay
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.autoDeploy(BaseDeployer.java:212)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.ThreadSafeAutoDeployer.autoDeploy(ThreadSafeAutoDeployer.java:36)
    at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployListener.deploy(PortletAutoDeployListener.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.deploy(AutoDeployDir.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.processFile(AutoDeployDir.java:211)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.scanDirectory(AutoDeployDir.java:275)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner.run(AutoDeployScanner.java:58)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war does not support this version of Liferay
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.java:898)
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.autoDeploy(BaseDeployer.java:209)
    ... 6 more
455 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:224] Add liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war to the blacklist
```

How do you use latest Vaadin version with latest version Liferay?

Comment: As long as the file is still in your deploy folder, it's not deployed. Do you see anything in the log that could help getting to the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key information is

```
liferay-vaadin-plugin-web-1.1.0.0.war does not support this version of Liferay
```

e.g. the authors probably have created/tested this plugin on 6.1 (likely), or got the declaration of compatible versions wrong (unlikely). In fact, if I look at [marketplace](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/27527287), the plugin indeed declares compatibility with 6.1, not 6.2. However, the marketplace app links to the [sourcecode](https://github.com/arcusys/liferay-vaadin-plugin) and the README file indicates that it might have already been ported to 6.2 - just not released on marketplace. You might want to check compiling it yourself.

As to your closing question of how to use the latest Vaadin version with Liferay, you might want to check [this article](https://www.liferay.com/web/matti/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-7-3-for-liferay-released)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have no experience with vaadin neither liferay. At first, I read Book of Vaadin and noticed a section about integration vaadin 7 into liferay and tried to deploy my first portlet in liferay.